# JavaFX ListView ListChangeListener.Change wrong for SelectionMode.MULTIPLE

Tags: listview, view, javafx, selection, multipleselection

The default selection model of JavaFX `ListView` seems to report wrong values to the listener in the `Change` object, if the selection mode is `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`. Is my interpretation of `Change` incorrect?

I have a list view with items "Julia", "Ian", "Sue", etc. The code below generates the following output:

Clicking first item "Julia" ("Julia" is selected, output correct):

```
from 0, to 1, removed 0, added 1
was added
removed:
added:
    Julia
selected:
    Julia
```

Shift + ArrowDown ("Julia" and "Ian" are selected):

```
from 0, to 1, removed 0, added 1    <-- should be from 1, to 2
was added
removed:
added:
    Julia    <-- should be Ian
selected:
    Julia
    Ian
```

Shift + ArrowDown ("Julia", "Ian", and "Sue" are selected):

```
from 0, to 1, removed 0, added 1    <-- should be from 2, to 3
was added
removed:
added:
    Julia    <-- should be Sue
selected:
    Julia
    Ian
    Sue
```

Any explanation for this behavior?

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Julia", "Ian", "Sue", "Matthew", "Hannah", "Stephan", "Denise");
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(items);

    MultipleSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = listView.getSelectionModel();
    selectionModel.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    ObservableList<String> selectedItems = selectionModel.getSelectedItems();

    selectedItems.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) -> {
        while (c.next()) {
            System.out.printf("from %d, to %d, removed %d, added %d\n", 
                    c.getFrom(), c.getTo(), c.getRemovedSize(), c.getAddedSize());
            if (c.wasAdded()) System.out.println("was added");
            if (c.wasRemoved()) System.out.println("was removed");
            if (c.wasPermutated()) System.out.println("was permutated");
            if (c.wasUpdated()) System.out.println("was updated");
            if (c.wasReplaced()) System.out.println("was replaced");
            System.out.println("removed:");
            for (String e : c.getRemoved()) {
                System.out.println("    " + e);
            }
            System.out.println("added:");
            for (String e : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                System.out.println("    " + e);
            }
            System.out.println("selected:");
            for (String e : selectedItems) {
                System.out.println("    " + e);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(listView, 300, 300);
    stage.setTitle("List View Sample");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug, probably in the behavior class for `ListView`. You should file a bug report at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com

Note that

```
ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
names.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) -> {
        while (c.next()) {
            System.out.printf("from %d, to %d, removed %d, added %d\n", 
                    c.getFrom(), c.getTo(), c.getRemovedSize(), c.getAddedSize());
            if (c.wasAdded()) System.out.println("was added");
            if (c.wasRemoved()) System.out.println("was removed");
            if (c.wasPermutated()) System.out.println("was permutated");
            if (c.wasUpdated()) System.out.println("was updated");
            if (c.wasReplaced()) System.out.println("was replaced");
            System.out.println("removed:");
            for (String e : c.getRemoved()) {
                System.out.println("    " + e);
            }
            System.out.println("added:");
            for (String e : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                System.out.println("    " + e);
            }
            System.out.println("selected:");
            for (String e : names) {
                System.out.println("    " + e);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    });
names.add("Julia");
names.add("Ian");
names.add("Sue");
```

behaves as you would expect.

Comment: I just filed a bug report. Thanks for the link.